# Why do Databases use HEAP to store table data while other structure like B-tree exists?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, index, btree, heap

Database Engines like `MS SQL Server` , `PostgreSQL` etc uses `HEAP` to store table data while using `B-tree` to store index data. Time complexity for most operations in B-tree is **O(log n)** while for HEAP it is **O(n)**. Even though B-tree is efficient by time factor why do databases still using HEAP(by default) over B-tree to store table data?

Answer (score 1):

When DBMS uses a Heap File, you still need to create indices. So finding records is still fast. All the **indices reference the physical location** of the records - which consists of the Page Number and some number inside the page. In PG you can get it with `select ctid, * from t`.

In case of the Clustered Indices - other **indices reference the value** by which the data is clustered.

**Pros of Heap files**:

- The Physical Location is always some fixed number of bytes. So the indices don't have to reference some potentially large value.
- You don't need to do `log(n)` search in the Clustered Index every time you found something in a Secondary Index. *Update*: interestingly, in SQL Server they still do some `log(n)` search even in case of Heap Files, see the comments.

**Pros of Clustered Indices**:

- If there's a column you frequently search by - it'll be faster to find the record right away in the Clustered Index. Rather than first find it in the Secondary Index, and then do a lookup by a physical location as happens with Heap Files.
- When record is updated, its ID (which is usually a Clustered Index by default) doesn't change. So all the Secondary Indices can keep referencing the same value. While with Heap Files it's a much more expensive operation - you need to find all the Secondary Indices referencing the record and add yet another physical location for the new version of the record (PG has an optimization called HOT which helps in some cases).
- Locality is better. Often when we insert a collection of records - they get requested at the same time. Their IDs will be close to each other if it's an autoincrement, and therefore they'll be located closely in the Clustered Index. And so if that page is already loaded into memory for the 1st record in a set, it's going to be faster to retrieve a neighboring record.
- No need to do explicit `order by pk_column` when running table scans. With Heap Files the way the client sees it - the order will be non-deterministic and will change with time.

At least these are the pros & cons that I could think of. Maybe there are more comprehensive overviews. Hopefully DBMS designers documented their decisions and the reasons behind them somewhere, I hope to run into those some day :)

But I don't think it's a simple, cut-and-dried decision. It makes some operations slower and more complicated, but keeps others faster and simpler. My hunch is that Heap File works better for append-mostly load, but gets slower when we have a lot of UPDATE & DELETE.

Comment: @Charlieface, you're talking about MS SQL Server, right? I'm curious why they have `log(n)`. PG doesn't need any search - the ctid (the analog of rid) already contains the page number and the tuple number inside the page.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I'm not too sure now.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Even SQL Server has RID of row pointing to heap. But still in MS documentation for SQL Server says, MSSQL cannot perform a direct seek on heap using RID so it need to perform table/heap scan. So I expect same happening with PostgreSQL, otherwise there is no need for indexes in Postgres :)

Comment: @mediocre, no, that's certainly not how it works. Note, that PG doesn't even have Clustered Indices - only Heaps. So if it worked the way you describe it, the indices would've been completely useless in PG :) So instead you have your Secondary Indices that reference `CTID`. E.g. `CTID=(2,8)` says it's the page=2, record=8. Then from this info it just loads page=2 and reads record=8 from it. That's it - you got your record. I'd assume MS SQL works similarly. But I can't easily find the explanation, seems like MS SQL simply doesn't explain how Heaps work.

Answer (score 1):

Heaps are mostly used for **staging** tables assuring the max **loading speed**, when for example you should load data from files, you do this by using bulk insert into a staging table that is not supposed to be queried by you users, it's just a "temporary" table, the absence of any order helps you to avoid any sort when loading data, but then you'll clear your data, do some checks and transformations and load the data in clustered table optimized for querying, assuring max speed and minimal locking for updates/deletes

Comment: Yes i understand  that tables should be indexed and a heap only useful for staging purposes. For SQL Server a clustered index make it sorted but PostgreSQL table data  always a in HEAP. So there is some reason why database designers chose heap over Btree to store table data. I like to know about that :)

Answer (score 1):

> Database Engines like `MS SQL Server` , `PostgreSQL` etc uses HEAP to store table data while using B-tree to store index data.

FWIW, in Microsoft SQL Server, adding a clustered index converts the table from a Heap to a B-Tree. It is no longer a Heap, after doing so. The clustered index, aka a B-Tree, **is** the table now.

Comment: The OP mentioned this fact in the question as he says "using HEAP over _B-tree to store table data_", so I'm guessing he knows about this :)

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Maybe it's a language barrier thing, but the way the question is worded implies that the table and an index are two different objects, and in Microsoft SQL Server at least, that's not necessarily true, when regarding the clustered index. (Not all database systems are the same though.) The point of my answer is to clearly say when a table has a clustered index in SQL Server, the statement "*using HEAP over B-tree to store table data*" is incorrect.

Comment: @J.D. yes i know how clustered indexes works in SQL server. But still by default the table data in MSSQL is in heap, and for PostgreSQL is always in heap regardless of indexes created . So my question was why the DB designers chose HEAP over b-tree to store table data. I saw somewhere it has some advantages of maintenance and less usage in terms of cache. But like to know more about this :)

Comment: @mediocre "*PostgreSQL is always in heap regardless of indexes created*" - Right, that's partly my point too, is that SQL Server is different than PostgreSQL in the sense that the table isn't always a Heap. I think the other answers convey the advantages and disadvantages of a Heap already. But in short, it's faster to insert data into a Heap, which is an unordered collection. But generally slower to read from one unless you're reading the entire dataset being stored in that table at one time. This makes Heaps typically more efficient for Staging type of tables.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the heap is default state of the table, but you are absolutely supposed to specify clustered index on the table - which will reorganize the table into a B-tree. The thing is, you need to specify the columns (and their order) used for creating that clustered index.

(Major exception is that when you create primary key on the table, it will create the clustered index based on that column(s).)

The key used for clustered index creation can be used for quick lookup, but when the key is `CustomerID` and you need to filter by `City`, then it won't help you at all. So it pays to pick the right columns for the clustered index.

Comment: I understand how indexes works, but my area of interest was why the designers chose heap over other DS to store table data (by default) while B-tree for index data?

Comment: Who knows? We can only guess. My guess would be that at the time of table creation, it is difficult/impossible to automatically pick good keys for the clustered index, so they leave it up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why `HEAP` over `B-tree`?- this is what I found from various resources ,

**1. Efficient use of storage/memory**

Heap uses array based storage which reduces  the overhead associated with maintaining pointers between nodes

**2. Less maintenance overhead**

Heap doesn’t require complex operations like `page-split` and merging during insert/delete or update

**3. Time complexity**

The time complexity for DML operations in a heap is the same as that in a B-tree - `O(log n)`

Now could the actual table data makes the use of clustering? For SQL Sever when the query using `clustered index` it can skip the `lookup` but if the query using `non-clustered index` it needs to lookup in the clustered index which is same as Postgres performing lookup in heap. There is a rumour that heap lookup outperform b-tree lookup :) https://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-indexes/rid-lookup-faster-key-lookup. Now that explains why PostgreSQL left the table data in the heap forever, additionaly it can save the resources on maintaining the B-trees for table data itself.(Yet PostgreSQL provides an alternative to clustered index using `CLUSTER` command.)

Even if indexes help with querying every database systems documented that number of indexes in a table should be controlled as it increases maintenance overhead of several B-trees which in turn compromising DML performance.

Considering all these I believe **`HEAP and B-tree` together makes the best blend for over all performance as HEAP aids in `DML` while B-tree aids in `Search`**.